# How to disable gzip compression in htaccess for a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate, mod-filter

I am looking to disable the gzip folder for folder xxx. looking in StackOverflow, I have tried this :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/xxx(.*) no-gzip dont-vary
```

But it doesn't work.

I have added in here :

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/flipbook(.*) no-gzip dont-vary
    # enables the filter
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    # non-textual entities should be already compressed
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    
</IfModule>
```

and even outside the mod_deflate module but nothing works.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/flipbook(.*) no-gzip dont-vary
> ```

This looks like it should work - for any URL that starts `/flipbook` (case-sensitive). Setting the `no-gzip` environment variable disables the DEFLATE filter of mod_deflate.

However, the `(.*)` part on the regex is entirely superfluous. And, unless you are specifically using the `dont-vary` env var in your own directives then this isn't doing anything. I don't think `dont-vary` is a "special" Apache env var. Apache has `force-no-vary`, which does what `dont-vary` is probably intended to do, however, I don't believe you should be disabling the `Vary` header anyway since mod_deflate applies the filter based on the `Accept-Encoding` HTTP request header sent from the client, so any intermediary caching proxies *should* cache based on this header. (Only certain proxies have a problem with this header.)

So, this should be written:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/flipbook" no-gzip
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#special

---

> ```
> # enables the filter
> SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
> ```

This doesn't just "enable the filter", it enables the DEFLATE filter on *all* responses. This basically renders the `AddOutputFilterByType` directives that follow superfluous, since you are already setting DEFLATE on everything. Generally, you don't want to set it on *everything*, which is presumably why you are using the `AddOutputFilterByType` directives.

So, you probably don't need the `SetOutputFilter` directive, if you are setting the DEFLATE on specific mime-types. OR, you use `SetOutputFilter` and remove the `AddOutputFilterByType` directives, but then you should still disable the filter on images and other already compressed media using the `no-gzip` env var.

> ```
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
> ```

You don't need all 3. Your server is setting just one mime-type when sending JavaScript files - which you can see in the HTTP response. You only need that one. (Probably `application/javascript`.)

---

#### Alternative solution

Instead of setting the `no-gzip` env var to disable mod_default, you could instead use an Apache `<If>` expression to conditionally set the output filters only when *not* accessing  URLs that start `/flipbook`.

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/flipbook/#">
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
</If>
```

You don't really need the `<IfModule>` wrapper unless you intend to port the same code to multiple servers where mod_deflate might not be enabled (and that is acceptable).

Comment: *Alternative solution* is best one from Apache 2.4+

Comment: many thanks..I tested the alternative solution and it worked perfectly. You really helped me a great deal. I admit I am not bad in php but I really suck with Apache :)

Comment: @dock21 You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer on the left below the voting arrows (to help other users and remove the question from the unanswered question queue). You can also upvote answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)